# command for enabling/disabling local area connection

Tags: windows, networking

for some reason, when a machine of mine first starts up from a fresh boot, the network doesn't work properly.  I usually fix this by enabling and disabling the 'local area connection'. These are the steps that I take to do the enabling and disabling:

1. control panel
2. View network connections
3. Right click 'local area connection', select 'disable'.
4. Right click 'local area connection', select 'enable'.

This fixes the problem, but I'm looking for a faster way to do it: is their a command that I can run from cmd.exe to perform the same action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLE
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLE
```

Syntax may depend and vary a bit between different versions of Windows...

Comment: The help text in XP explains this works only for non-LAN only...  I get the following error when I try:
`One or more essential parameters not specified`
`The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.`

Comment: Found another way to type in command, to get another similar error:
`Dedicated interfaces can not be connected, disconnected, enabled, or disabled.`
`Cannot complete this function.`

Comment: Probably a known issue with XP that won't be fixed, considering how old and out-of-support it is: https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/kb/262265

Answer (score 2):

You could try ipconfig /renew

Comment: you could put a batch file in the startup menu with ipconfig /release ipconfig /renew.  This is more of a work-around though.  What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a laptop?  On many laptops, your NIC will be disabled if you are running on battery power.   On my Dell for example, there is an item in Control Panel called "Internal NIC Configuration" which controls this behavior.  You may have something similar, or it may be in your power settings.
Other place to check would be in the BIOS settings - see if there is any setting that would disable the NIC.

Comment: It's not a laptop.  I thought it was an issue with Vista, but I've since installed win7 and the issue is still present.  

After reading your advice, I'm going to play with the power management options and see if that addresses the root cause. I'll keep you updated, thanks!